# Where does macOS Chrome store its cookie block list?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, cookies

I had dozens of sites listed to block cookies under `chrome://settings/content/cookies?search=cookie`, but now suddenly (after an update, I'd guess) the list is blank.

[image: screenshot]

Where is this stored within my user library folder (`~/Library/`)? I'd like to check my Time Machine for the previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the file by fishing around in Finder: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences`

It's composed of minified JSON. The object I wanted began on line 4790 with `"cookies": {`. I found it by searching for a known site-name to block. The cookies object's sub-objects are structured thus:

```
"[*.]site-name-here.com,*": {
    "last_modified": "13168987493212369",
    "setting": 2
},
```

They all have setting 2, by the way.

I quit Chrome app, opened both old and new versions of the Preferences file in an online JSON prettifier, copy–pasted the missing text (including added space characters), saved the file, closed the file, relaunched Chrome, and checked the list again within the UI (`chrome://settings/content/cookies?search=cookie`). All blocked sites are restored. I then checked the Preferences file, and it had re-minified itself.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS, the Chrome setting files are stored in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/`.

You should search for files which have "cookie" in their filename (search for `name:cookie`) in finder, and restore all of them. With any luck, you'll get your data back.

If this doesn't work, try restoring other files, or even the complete directory. See this [ForensicWiki](https://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) page for more details on the different files in the directory. Good luck!